# How can I make custom resizing for images?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-assets, image-size

Although some of my images in android studio are the same when I was creating them, they are in different sizes in android studio. I need a default image size and a custom image size here. My piece of code is as follows:

`public class CreateScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private CreateScreenBinding binding;
private String taskName;
private EditText editTextTaskName;
private int selectedLogoResourceId;
private ArrayList<Task> tasks;
Button saveButton;
DBOpenHelper db;
public String selectedDrawablePath;










SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //AppDatabase appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(this);//for open the database
    db = DBOpenHelper.getInstance(this);


    //Linking create_screen.xml layout file to CreateScreen Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.create_screen);

    binding = CreateScreenBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    binding.selectLogo1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo3.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo4.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo5.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo6.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo7.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo8.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo9.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo10.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo11.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo12.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo13.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo14.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    binding.selectLogo15.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparant));
    ImageView LogoView = binding.LogoView;
    selectedDrawablePath = "timer";


    binding.selectLogo1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.timer);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/timer.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "timer";


        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.graphic);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/graphic.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "graphic";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tie);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/tie.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "tie";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/book.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "book";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/music.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "music";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dumbell);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/dumbell.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "dumbell";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/ball.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "ball";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/home.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "home";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pencil);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/pencil.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "pencil";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.computer);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/computer.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "computer";

        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.software);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/software.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "software";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.film);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/film.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "film";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.plane);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/plane.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "plane";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/dollar.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "dollar";
        }
    });
    binding.selectLogo15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sun);
            //selectedDrawablePath = "res/drawable/sun.png";
            selectedDrawablePath = "sun";


        }
    });
    editTextTaskName = findViewById(R.id.editTextTaskName);



    Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String workName = editTextTaskName.getText().toString();
            int workingHours = 0;
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
            String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

            Cursor csr = db.getAllDataAsCursor();
            boolean isDuplicate = false;


            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                String existingWorkName = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("workname"));
                if (existingWorkName.equals(workName)) {

                    isDuplicate = true;
                    break;

                }
            }

            if (!isDuplicate) {
                // if doesnt exist same task of this task save it
                db.saveWorkRecord(workName, selectedDrawablePath, formattedDate, workingHours);
                csr = db.getAllDataAsCursor();
                DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
                finish();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(CreateScreen.this, "There is already a task with this name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });



}
```

}`

How can I resize the image?